# Nest Camera streaming with HLS / Raspberry

Tags: nest-api

I'm streaming a Nest Camera on a RaspberryPi but I get a lot of errors like these:

```
[https @ 0x12dec30] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[https @ 0x12df470] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[https @ 0x13610d0] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[https @ 0x130ff30] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
skipping 1 segments ahead, expired from playlists
[https @ 0x133cea0] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[https @ 0x133cea0] HTTP error 404 Not Found
[hls,applehttp @ 0x12cb170] Failed to open segment of playlist 0
[https @ 0x1305900] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[https @ 0x1305900] HTTP error 404 Not Found
[hls,applehttp @ 0x12cb170] Failed to open segment of playlist 0
[https @ 0x12d2cb0] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[https @ 0x12d2cb0] HTTP error 404 Not Found
[hls,applehttp @ 0x12cb170] Failed to open segment of playlist 0
```

Somebody tried to do this or do you have a clue about these warnings?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by you are streaming a nest cam on a raspberry pi. Can you elaborate?

Comment: A Nest cam can be "public" and you get a link with an embeddable flash player that is showing the live stream. 
I saw that they expose also HLS format (https://xxx.m3u8)
Omxplayer on the RPi can read that stream and use the GPU to decode the h264 video.